# Where should I declare/instantiate my Store object to keep it available while app running?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, storekit

I have an iOS app written in Swift where I have written code for the store in it's own class (Store). I then have a view controller (StoreController) which displays the product details and presents buttons so that the user can buy/restore purchases. I am using the delegate pattern.

My question is where should I create the Store object? Currently I'm declaring it as a property of StoreController which I think is wrong. I would prefer to be able to create it when my app loads and keep it until it quits.

The current problem is that if I test it and navigate to the StoreController view (initiating the request via Store) then press 'back' the app freezes. I assume because it's waiting on the response?

I saw one example online where someone created it in the AppDelegate file but this didn't work for me as I wasn't able to reference it from my StoreController.

This is my Store class:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

protocol ClassStoreDelegate: class {
func storeUpdateReceived(store: Store)
}

class Store: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

// Properties
weak var delegate: ClassStoreDelegate?
var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()
var defaults = UserDefaults.standard // Where we save whether the user is pro
var localTitle: String?
var localDescription: String?
var localPrice: String?

// Methods
// Calling the delegate method
func storeUpdate() {
    delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
}

// Buy the product
func buy() {
    for product in list {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "com.squidgylabs.pro") {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
        }
    }
}

// Restore products
func restore() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}


func getProducts() {
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.squidgylabs.pro")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
    }
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        list.append(product)
    }
    // Update labels
    localTitle = list[0].localizedTitle
    localDescription = list[0].localizedDescription

    // Format the price and display
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    if let formattedPrice = formatter.string(from: list[0].price){
        localPrice = ("buy \(formattedPrice)")
        delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    let transactionsArray = queue.transactions
    if (transactionsArray.isEmpty) {
        delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
    }
    else {
        for transaction in transactionsArray {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "com.squidgylabs.pro":
                defaults.set(true, forKey: "pro")
                delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
            default:
                delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
            }
        }
    }
}

func buyProduct() {
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            let prodID = p.productIdentifier
            switch prodID {
            case "com.squidgylabs.pro":
                defaults.set(true, forKey: "pro")
                delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
            default:
                        delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
            }
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        case .failed:
            delegate?.storeUpdateReceived(store: self)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        case .restored:
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

}
```

And this is my StoreController (view controller):

```
import UIKit

class StoreController: UIViewController, ClassStoreDelegate   {

// Properties
let store = Store()

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var localTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var localDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var buy: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var restore: UIButton!

// Actions
@IBAction func buy(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("buy pressed")
    store.buy()
}

@IBAction func restore(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("restore pressed")
    store.restore()
}

// Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    store.delegate = self // bind the delegate like this?

    // Get list of products for the store
    localTitle.isEnabled = false
    localDescription.isEnabled = false
    buy.isEnabled = false
    restore.isEnabled = false
    self.navigationItem.title = "Store"
    // update once the list of products is got from the store object
    store.getProducts()
}

// Running the delegate update
func storeUpdateReceived(store: Store) {
    print("storeUpdateReceived activated")
    if ((store.localTitle) != nil) {
        localTitle.text = store.localTitle!
        localDescription.text = store.localDescription
        buy.setTitle(store.localPrice, for: .normal)
        localTitle.isEnabled = true
        localDescription.isEnabled = true
        buy.isEnabled = true
        restore.isEnabled = true
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right - instantiate it in your AppDelegate.  You know it will be called once and only once, so it's a good place to initialise things.

You can access the AppDelegate from anywhere in your app

```
appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
```